How can i remove the margins from my PDF with jsPDF?
I'm trying to download some data from a table in PDF format. Downloading on CSV works just fine, but when i try to download the PDF, it generates with a left, top, bottom and maybe even right, though it's not visible.

This is the code that is generating the PDF:
  function DownloadPDF(data) {
    if (!data || data.length === 0) {
  
      if (data.length === 0) {
        setTimeout(() =>{
          const modal = document.querySelector('.modelalert')
          modal.style.display = 'none'
        },2500)
         
        const modal = document.querySelector('.modelalert')
        modal.style.display = 'block'
        modal.innerHTML='Nenhum dado disponível para download'    
        return;
      } 
  
    }
  
    const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
  
    
    var pdf = new window.jspdf.jsPDF();

    const tableData = data.map(obj => headers.map(header => obj[header]));
  
    pdf.autoTable({
      head: [headers],
      body: tableData,
      styles: { 
        cellWidth: 'wrap',
        fillColor: [255, 255, 255]
      },
      willDrawCell: (data) => {
        if (data.section === 'body' && data.row.index % 2 === 1) {
          pdf.setFillColor(230); // Cor cinza
        }
      },
      didParseCell: (data) => {
        const cell = data.cell;
        const lineHeight = pdf.internal.getFontSize() / pdf.internal.scaleFactor;
        const cellHeight = cell.height / pdf.internal.scaleFactor;
        const lines = pdf.splitTextToSize(cell.text, cell.width);
        const textHeight = lines.length * lineHeight;
        if (textHeight > cellHeight) {
          cell.height = textHeight * pdf.internal.scaleFactor;
        }
      }
    });
  
    pdf.save('relatorio.pdf');
  }

I've already tried these alternatives to remove the margin
First try
pdf.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
Second try
var pdf = new window.jspdf.jsPDF({
  orientation: 'portrait',
  unit: 'mm',
  format: 'a4',
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  marginTop: 10,
  marginBottom: 10
});

Third try
    pdf.autoTable({
      head: [headers],
      body: tableData,
      styles: { 
        cellWidth: 'wrap', // Ajusta a largura das células para caber o conteúdo
        fillColor: [255, 255, 255] // Define a cor de preenchimento das células como branco
      },
      margins {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        right: 10,
      },

None of these worked, in fact, they don't seem to change anything at all.
How can i make the PDF's content fit the page correctly?
